# How to read a text+numeric TSV into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This should be trivial, but I can't find the answer in the MATLAB documentation.  I have a TSV file consisting of ~60,000 rows and 38 columns.  The first row has the names of the columns, and the first column consists entirely of alphanumeric strings.  The remaining entries are all floating-point numbers (although, in many cases the value is expressed as just 0, without an explicit decimal point).

How can I read this data into MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB provides a function `textscan` for this purpose. The second argument is the format specifier. In your case, the first field is a string, so we use `%s`, the remaining fields are float values, so we use `%f`. You will need 37 repeats of `%f` - a few more than in this example:

```
fid = fopen('yourfile.tsv');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

`HeaderLines` tells `textscan` how many lines to skip before starting. You mention that the first line in your file contains the column names, so we skip `1` line.

Comment: A useful tip here: because you have 38 columns in your file, this requires you to have 37 '%f's in the second argument of text scan. Using `repmat` saves you from typing/miscounting: `['%s' repmat('%f',1,37)]`.