# Confused with .tsv files in MATLAB (converting to a Matrix?)

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a .tsv file that I wish to open in MATLAB, however I am having several problems with this.

I have tried the following

```
fid = fopen('data.tsv');
C = textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,8)], 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

and got some weird values that had nothing to do with my file.  I also tried:

```
data = dlmread('data.tsv', '\t');
```

and got this

```
Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==> Participant Assessment  
Experiment  Block   Trial
Answer  Reaction    Timestamp   Free Response\n
```

Is there some way I can get it to ignore the header, or am I doing it totally wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a text+numeric TSV into MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207518/how-to-read-a-textnumeric-tsv-into-matlab)

Comment: Like I said I tried that

Answer (score 0):

With `dlmread` you can specify where to start reading in the file.  This is one of the few times that MATLAB indexing begins at 0 - [0,0] is the first row, first column.  Therefore, to ignore the first row (containing your header):

```
data = dlmread('data.tsv','\t', 1, 0);
```

This will only work if all the values (other than the header lines you skip) are numeric.

Your example with `textscan` also looks fine to me (provided that the format supplied is correct and there is indeed only one header line). C will be a cell array; to obtain the data from each column use C{n} where n is the column number.

Rather than skipping the header line, it's sometimes useful to just read it in to a separate value:

```
fid = fopen('data.tsv');
C_header = textscan(fid, '%s',9);
C = textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,8)]);
fclose(fid);
```