# How to import column of numbers from mixed string numerical text file

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

Variations of this question have already been asked several times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207518/how-to-read-a-textnumeric-tsv-into-matlab).  However, I can't seem to get this to work for my data.

I have a text file with 3 columns.  First and third columns are floating point numbers.  Middle column is strings.  I'm only interested in getting the first column really.

Here's what I tried:

```
filename=fopen('heartbeatn1nn.txt');
A = textscan(filename,'%f','HeaderLines',0);
fclose(filename);
```

When I do this A comes out as just a single number--the first element in the column.  How do I get the whole column?  I've also tried this with the '.tsv' file extension, same result.

Also tried:

```
filename=fopen('heartbeatn1nn.txt');
formatSpec='%f';sizeA=[1 Inf];
A = fscanf(filename,formatSpec,sizeA);
fclose(filename);
```

with same result.

Could the file size be a problem?  Not sure how many rows but probably quite a few since file size is 1.7M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns in your text file are separated by single whitespace characters your format specification should look like this:

```
A = textscan(filename,'%f %s %f');
```

`A` now contains the complete file content. To obtain the first column:

```
first_col = A{:,1};
```

Alternatively, you can tell `textscan` to skip the unneeded fields with the `*` option:

```
first_col = cell2mat( textscan(filename, '%f %*s %*f') );
```

This returns only the first column.